# Remove empty lines from a text file

Tags: perl

I have some code to clean files line by line in perl. One part of the code checks lines for spaces and removes those spaces. Based on my logic, it should also remove lines that are just blank lines, but it does not.

```
$file = "myfile.txt";  
open (IN, $file) || die "Cannot open file ".$file." for read";       
@lines=<IN>;    
close IN;  

open (OUT, ">", $file) || die "Cannot open file ".$file." for write";  
foreach $line (@lines)  
{    

    #removes all spaces from lines and but won't remove empty lines (it should).
    $line =~ tr/ //d;
    #remove double quotes from file
    $line =~ s/\x22//g;

   print OUT $line;    
}    
close OUT;
```

How can I add to this code to remove all lines that are just empty lines? To turn this:

```
This is "line 1".
This is "line 2".

This is "line 4".
This is "line 5".
```

into this:

```
Thisisline1.
Thisisline2.
Thisisline4.
Thisisline5.
```

Comment: You don't account for the newline.

Comment: @ikegami it works in command line `perl -i.bak -nlwe "tr/ //d; print if length" myfile.txt` but when I put it in a script it isn't working.

Comment: `-nl` chomps the newline and re-adds the newline. Also, `print if length` is different than `print`.

Comment: You confuse spaces and newlines: they're different characters.

Comment: Your code is much longer than needed. It is poor style to hardcode filenames into your scripts - it is much better (and a Unix convention) to use arguments to the script to denote input file(s) and if no arguments are given, read the input from stdin (so you can use the script in a pipe or read the input from the console for testing) and to write the  output to stdout (so you can write it to the console or to a pipe as well.  It is also poor style to unnecessarily store your lines in an array. If you agree to fix these things, your script can just become `while (<>) { s/ //g; print if /./ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is what you had originally:

```
>perl -MO=Deparse -i.bak -nlwe "tr/ //d; print if length"
BEGIN { $^I = ".bak"; }
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    tr/ //d;
    print $_ if length $_;
}
```

There are significant differences from what you have now. Specifically, you don't account for the newline. You could use the following:

```
for my $line (@lines) {    
   $line =~ s/["\s]//g;
   print OUT "$line\n" if length($line);
}
```

`\s` matches all whitespace including newlines.

Comment: ikegami, What can I add to my code to allow me to specify the file name in the command line on Windows CMD? I am having trouble finding that because you need to have two backslashes instead of one in the path name you specify. And also create a backup .bak file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chomp($line)` to remove the newline and then check if `$line` is equal to empty string.

This will also avoid modifying your code any further.

Answer (score 1):

When in a loop of lines like that, that is being either returned in a new array or being printed, I always just use:

```
next if($line =~ s/^\s*$/);
```

which should skip processing on blank lines.

Comment: You mean `^\s*$` ?! `$` marks the end of a line, not `&`.

Comment: not `s/^\s*$/`, just `/^\s*$/` works

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perlvar.html) to modify the file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "myfile.txt";

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    tr/ "//d;           # Remove spaces and double quotes
    print if ! /^$/;    # Skip blank lines
}
# unlink "$file$^I"; # Optionally delete backup
```

For other methods for modifying a file, just check out [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)